# AWS Amplify: Return tags and/or metadata with Storage.list

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify to list the files in an S3 Bucket:

```
Storage.list('path/', { level: 'private' })
.then(result => {
    // Process Result
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

`result` is the standard json containing `eTag`, `key`, `lastModified` and `size`.

I want to add custom attributes to each file - e.g. a friendly displayName and visibility flag - and to have these attributes returned when i run `Storage.list`

I can add the attributes as metadata or tags but how can i retrieve them as part of `Storage.list`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if some of you guys are still looking for this.

But as April 2022, it's still not a thing it seems.

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/download/q/platform/js/#frequently-asked-questions

> You cannot only get file metadata yet.

You can follow one of the requests to add this here

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1550